# boost::posix_time::microsec_clock to double seconds with microsecond resolution

Tags: c++, boost, posix

I tried to find the answer all over the internet. I need a timestamp in seconds with microsecond resolution.

```
boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
// not really getting any further here
double now_seconds = 0; // a value like 12345.123511, time since epoch in seconds with usec precision
```

**UPDATE:**

It is sufficient to use the beginning of the current day as the epoch -- i.e. a 24h timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**N.B.** This answer provides a generic method that allows an arbitrary epoch, since it was written before the update. [fonZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080633/fonz)'s answer is a good simplification when a timestamp relative to beginning of a current day is needed.

---

I'm not aware of an existing function in the library that would do exactly what you ask for, but with the help of documentation it is simple to come up your own in a few lines.

Subtract your `ptime` from a `ptime` representing the epoch, to get a [`time_duration`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.time_duration) representing the amount of time elapsed since epoch. The `time_duration` class provides `total_microseconds()`. Scale the result appropriately to get seconds.

### Code Sample

```
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>

double seconds_from_epoch(boost::posix_time::ptime const& t)
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime const EPOCH(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));
    boost::posix_time::time_duration delta(t - EPOCH);
    return (delta.total_microseconds() / 1000000.0);
}


int main()
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime now(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time());
    std::cout << boost::format("%0.6f\n") % seconds_from_epoch(now);
    return 0;   
}
```

<kbd>[Sample on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92f70f8f36bd920f)</kbd>

Console output:

```
1497218065.918929
```

Comment: Just be careful what kind of calculations you do with these doubles after the fact. The epoch in microseconds is getting so large that you only have a few remaining bits. For one thing, this means that you might get weird durations if you take differences of short timespans, since 1/1000000.0 is not precisely expressible in binary form. E.g. a 2 microsecond duration computed as a - b where a and b are microseconds since the epoch might end up being expressed as 2.125.

Comment: @cnettel Good point. Depending on the use case, perhaps a different epoch may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I found a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, at least it seems to work correctly (didn't bother to check the actual values so be my guest if you want to correct me).

```
boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
double sec = now.time_of_day().total_microseconds()/1000000.0;
```

Comment: That's only going to give you the time offset since the beginning of the given day.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for answering. I forgot the write the division. And I need a 24h timestamp so that's all good.

Comment: Oh, OK :) BTW, one more issue. The result of `total_microseconds` is a `long`, so you should divide by a `double` constant to avoid integer division -- i.e. divide by `1000000.0`. 2) the variable name `usec` is no longer correct. ... OK, two issues :)